# What is this evergreen plant?

Tags: identification, shrubs, evergreens

Update 7/22/21

It flowered today, do you recognize this flower?
[image]

---

I got it from a local nursery (USDA Zone 10a) and it was just labeled as an evergreen shrub. What is it and how should I care for it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some kind of escallonia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be *Escallonia rubra*.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a euonymus , usually they are variegated in the landscape trade.

Comment: I searched for euonymus but didn’t see any plant flowers like this.